# How to skip first few rows of text while importing csv with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis, data-cleaning

We receive a csv file from our vendor everyday.
However, the format is like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6">#Receiver</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">#DateTime</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">#Address</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Col1</td>
    <td>Col2</td>
    <td>Col3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>10%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>20%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>10%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to use pandas to read the table which starts at row 5 and column 3.
How could I skip the first few rows?

Thanks.

Comment: this isn't a csv. A csv file stands for comma separated values

Comment: I failed to demonstrate the table in html here. I just wanna show an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following code will help you

```
import pandas as pd

html_text = '''<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6">#Receiver</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">#DateTime</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">#Address</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Col1</td>
    <td>Col2</td>
    <td>Col3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>10%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>20%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>10%</td>
  </tr>
</table>'''
ROWS_YOU_WANT_TO_SKIP=3
df = pd.read_html(html_text, skiprows = ROWS_YOU_WANT_TO_SKIP)
df.head()
```

so, you just give skiprows a value based on number of rows you want to ignore

Comment: @DataHolic, great. mark it as answered if its the answer you are looking for